# Please tell me the proper use of swift's comment out.

Tags: swift, xcode

Please tell me the proper use of swift's comment out. The following two are subtly different colors of green on xcode. How do you use it?

**No1**

```
/**



 */
```

**No2**

```
/*



 */
```

Answer (score 24):

The version with two asterisks, as well as an inline comment using three slashes (`///`), will show up in the generated interface that you can see by choosing "Jump to Generated Interface" from the "Navigate" menu.

The version with only one asterisk, as well as inline comments with only two slashes (`//`), will be hidden from the generated interface.

The purpose of `/** **/` and `///` is for you to provide documentation for your APIs, similar to comments in the header files in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a [Markdown comment that goes into QuickHelp](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SymbolDocumentation.html).

The second one is just a comment.